# Why did Tor stop working? (Won't launch)

Tags: xubuntu, browser, tor, tor-browser

I've been using Tor browser for months but, possibly after the latest update, it now refuses to launch.

I set Tor to 'run in terminal' so I could see any errors and when starting it shows this, but never does anything else:

[image]

Typing `tor` in terminal it seems fine but again, it never actually launches:

[image]

Tor doesnt show in `top`, but after checking port 9050 with `sudo netstat -plnt | fgrep 9050` I can see that Tor is running:

[image]

Edit: I removed Tor completely (it was previously installed from software centre) and reinstalled from ppa:micahflee/ppa and I still have the same problem... Tor won't launch

Does anyone else have this problem or know how I can fix it?

Comment: I have the same problem, buto don't know how to fix. I'm surfing the net searching for it

Comment: Did you have any luck?

Comment: actually I found nothing. But I could try a daily build of the xubuntu 20.10. With it tor works without problems. I don't know if this can be useful.

Comment: Tor Browser needs the C++ libs to be mem-mapped.  This issue was fixed in 20.10 and has a pending fix in 20.04's proposed repositories of torbrowser-launcher.  (AppArmor issues don't go to your stderr on the terminal - they go to the system logs only, this is a known issue - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/torbrowser-launcher/+bug/1897302 )

Comment: Thanks, if you post it as an answer i'll mark it correct.